# prime factors of $3^{32}-2^{32}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question asks to find 4 prime factors of $3^{32}-2^{32}$ under $100$.
My take:I factorized it and the obvious ones are $5, 97$ and $13$.I cannot find the last one ,however.I was wondering if we could prove the number is even but that has not worked out well.So what is the other factor and how do we find it?

Comment: "that has not worked out well." That is because the number is not even: work modulo 2, or (equivalently) notice that $3^{32}$ is odd (because it is the product of lots of odd numbers) and $2^{32}$ is even (because it is the product of lots of even numbers) and odd - even = odd.

Comment: @Billy I think the OP meant 'could prove the number of factors under 100 is even' (which would necessitate there being more than the three of them found), since $3^{32}-2^{32}$ is trivially odd.  But I can't imagine any good way of establishing the parity of the number of factors beneath a given bound.

Comment: I assume you started by using repeated difference-of-squares factorization to get $(3^{16} + 2^{16})(3^8 + 2^8)(3^4 + 2^4)(3^2 + 2^2)(3^2 - 2^2)$, for which the last three factors evaluate to 97, 13, and 5.

Answer (score 4):

If you are able to factor the number (which I did with wolframalpha), you will get $$5\cdot 13\cdot 17\cdot 97\cdot 401\cdot 3041\cdot 14177$$
which immediately answers your question.

However most likely the intent of the person asking was for you to use indirect means to determine small factors.  For example, to tell whether $5$ is a factor, we calculate the expression modulo 5: $$3^{32}-2^{32}\equiv 3^{32}-(-3)^{32}\equiv 3^{32}-(-1)^{32}3^{32}\equiv 0$$

Additional example as requested, modulo 13:

$$3^4= 81\equiv 3, 3^{16}=(3^4)^4\equiv 3, 3^{32}=(3^{16})^2\equiv 9$$
$$2^4=16\equiv 3, 2^{16}=(2^4)^4\equiv 3^4\equiv 3, 2^{32}=(2^{16})^2\equiv 9$$

Comment: What I meant by factoring it was break it down using formula for factorizing a^2-b^2.

Comment: For some reason I cannot find 17 though.

Comment: @rah4927, that only helps so much since you will still need to find prime factors for $a^m+b^m$ terms.

Comment: Also, since you say "last one" I assume that you've been told there are 4.  Your ad hoc method will not prove that there are only 4, so you are relying on this information in your solution.

Comment: @rah4927 $3^8 + 2^8 = 17 \cdot 401$.

Comment: @Vadim I am sorry I forgot to mention 4.But how do we figure out 17.It would require tedious amount of calculation.

Comment: @vadim123 It would be helpful for the OP to show how you obtained the factorization.

Comment: Even by using your method,it would take some time.But judging by the fact that it was an Olympiad question,I think it would rely less on triAL and error.

Comment: When,we are going to calculate the expression modulo 13,how are we going to prove it congruent to 0?

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to find the other factor via your method, you would have to say:
$$
3^{32}-2^{32}=(3^8-2^8)(3^8+2^8)(3^{16}+2^{16})
$$
and then note that $(3^8+2^8)=6817=401\cdot17$

Answer (score 2):

Since the algebraic factors of $3^{32}-2^{32}$ are all sums of two (coprime) squares, we only need to look for primes that are $1$ mod $4$.  This suggests checking $17$ once $5$ and $13$ have been found, and we quickly see that Fermat's theorem shows $3^{32} \equiv 2^{32} \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$.

**Edit**: By "algebraic factors" I mean those arising from the factorization of $x^{32} - y^{32}$ over $\mathbb Q[x,y]$:

$$3^{32} - 2^{32} = (3^{16}+2^{16})(3^8+2^8)(3^4+2^4)(3^2+2^2)(3+2)(3-2).$$

Comment: Do you mean the little theorem?

Comment: @vadim123 Your example is specious because the $3$ is only coming from the "tail factor" $5-2$.  In this question that factor is $3-2 = 1$, which produces no primes.  Primes congruent to 3 mod 4 **cannot** occur in sums of coprime squares.

Comment: @rah4927 Yes, of course the little theorem.

Comment: Please explain why the sum of two coprime squares can only have factors congruent to 1 mod 4.

Comment: @vadim123 This is really quite standard: if $(x,y)=1$ then any prime $p$ dividing $x^2+y^2$ must not divide $x$.  Therefore $(y/x)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$, which means $p$ is either $1$ mod $4$ or $2$.  This is *precisely* the reason why $4k+3$ primes can only occur in pairs for general $x^2+y^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually breakimg that by a^2-b^2 is just useful for only the 3 answers you have got, but im sure you did not check out the nos. with the bigger powers. If you had checked 3^8 +2^8, which is 6817 , it is divisible by 17 (and 401). And by the way anything odd minus even is always odd. So this no. only has odd factors (because all of them are in form 3^x+-2^y. Here i mean plus minus.)